# Why Yotzer HaAdam and not Borei HaAdam?

Tags: blessing

when saying a blessing on fruits we say "borei pri haetz" who created the fruit of the tree.

by a human we say "Yotzer haAdam" and not borei haAdam". why the change?

the term Borei (creation) is generally used with respect to God only whereas Yotzer (forming) is used with respect to humans also.

Comment: Why do you think they'd be similar?

Comment: Why should they be the same?

Comment: To make the question stronger: The posuk refers to the root of borei for Man, but not for fruit.

Comment: Why not to ask about the beginning of the blessing Asher Yatsar or simply about the current asher Yatsar bracha?

Comment: See Gemara Ketubot 8a:
>לוי איקלע לבי רבי בהלוליה דר''ש בריה בריך חמש רב אסי איקלע לבי רב אשי בהלוליה דמר בריה בריך שית לימא בהא קמיפלגי דמ''ס __חדא יצירה__ הואי ומ''ס __שתי יצירות__ הואי לא דכ''ע חדא יצירה הואי מ''ס בתר מחשבה אזלינן ומ''ס בתר מעשה אזלינן כי הא דרב יהודה רמי כתיב {בראשית א-כז} __ויברא__ אלהים את האדם בצלמו וכתיב {בראשית ה-ב} זכר ונקבה __בראם__ הא כיצד בתחלה עלה במחשבה לבראות שנים ולבסוף נברא אחד
The Gemara makes the question strongest

Answer (score 3):

*Bara* is used when mankind is first created "male and female" (Bereshith 1:27), like all the rest of the animals (see Sforno there) during the general narrative about the world, predominantly in the first chapter. But it is only later, in the narrative specifically about the garden, where it refers to HaShem "forming" Adam (2:7).

If you read RambaN and Sforno there, they discuss the differences between the reference to *bara* versus *yassar* in these two passages, the latter meaning to merely alter an existing object, whereas the former usually infers an initial bring into existence (although Ibn `Ezra and Gersonides dispute this point, but that is not relevant right now).

During the **sheva` berakhoth**, we say "yosser adham" because while humanity was first created as essentially an animal creature like all others (Sforno), God later "formed" him into a different man - one that was sedentary, agrarian, domesticated animals, and - most of all - **practiced marriage**.

"Yotzer HaAdam" indicates the new state of man just before he is given his wife by God, like a man under the *huppah*.

Hope this helps.